# Excel: Find matching values in compare first column then compare 2nd column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to find out under the same invoice, having the duplicate product
The first condition is must be same invoice number, and the 2nd condition is same product name.

Any idea how to do it in Excel?

[image: Find Duplication for 2 column]

Comment: Use COUNTIFS() with conditional formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a step by step:

- select all data from cell A1 to the last row of data in column B, for example A1 to B100
- on the Home ribbon click Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine ...
- enter this formula

  =COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$100,$A1,$B$1:$B$100,$B1)>1
- click the Format button and select a fill color.
- Hit OK on all dialogs.

[image]